# Append a div outside of the input parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im fairly new to javascript and I just can't figure this out despite my attempt in researching. How do I track the change of a input within a div and trigger an append to an outside div? My code goes as follow:

Append h3 with "Pending" once ".image-value" input has a change in value

```
<!-- APPEND <h3> -->
<h3>Best Overall Costume<div class="pending">Pending</div></h3>
<div>
  <div class="select-form">
    <img src="images/vote.jpg" data-value="image_value">
    <img src="images/vote.jpg" data-value="image_value2">
    <img src="images/vote.jpg" data-value="image_value3">
    <img src="images/vote.jpg" data-value="image_value4">
    <img src="images/vote.jpg" data-value="image_value5">
    <!-- Track the change of this input -->
    <input type="hidden" class="image-value" name="selected_image" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
function changeStatus(statusValue) {
    $("input",".select-form").val(statusValue).trigger("change");
}

$("input",".select-form").change(function(){
    if (!$(this).val()){
        $("<div class='pending'>Pending</div>").appendTo($("h3").prev($(this)));
    }
});
```

But that didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

place an empty div where you want your new div and give it an id i.e(`<div id='myDiv'><div>`) and then append what you want like this.

```
$( "#myDiv" ).append( "<div class='pending'>Pending</div>" );
```

You can also check [Append Explained](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

for more explanations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a couple things here... First, I'm not sure why you had it all in a named function. When you're using event listeners that often isn't necessary.

Then, I don't know what the val check was for, so I reversed it.

Finally, I'm using `one()`, which only runs once. This case seemed to call for that.

```
$('.select-form').one('change', 'input', function () {
    if ( $(this).val() ) { alert('asdgf');
        $("<div class='pending'>Pending</div>")
            .appendTo($(this).parent().prev('h3'));
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ssum8ppx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("input",".select-form").on("change", function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     if (!$this.val()){
            var elem = $('<h3>Best Overall Costume<div class="pending">Pending</div></h3>');                
            $this.parent().parent().before(elem);
     }
});
```

you can also place a check, that if the pending div is already added, not to add it again.

Of course this solution assumes that there are no other nested divs between the target div(before which you want to append) and the input control